# How to kill a thread that is waiting on synchronized resource?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Suppose a class named `Prey` extends `Thread` and an Object of `Prey` named `deer` is in waiting state on a `synchronized` resource. Now I want to kill this `deer` by force which is in waiting state. Which one of the following is correct way to kill the `deer`.

1. `deer.interrupt();`
2. `deer.notify();
    deer.interrupt();`
3. `deer.notify();
    deer.killmeBoolean(true);`
4. `deer.killmeBoolean(true);
    deer.notify();`

where `killmeBoolean(boolean)` is used to set a flag so that `deer` thread can be terminated from `while(flag)` loop.

Comment: Looks like homework to me.

Comment: It's 1) if the code you interrupt is written correctly. But there is no guarantee for that: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/ (or read the jcip.net book). `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is usually (minus code that doesn't set the interrupted flag when stopped via InterruptedException) as good as a custom boolean so you don't need one.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar an interrupt will not release any locks unless the thread is implemented to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `notify` or `notifyAll` on *the resource the thread is waiting on*. This will tell the thread that the resource is "ready" and to continue with its work. Notice that the thread still can only continue when the lock on the resource is released.

**Or**, you call `deer.interrupt()` to tell the thread to stop what it's doing. This will cancel the waiting operation by throwing an `InterruptedException`. It is generally expected that the thread will then clean up and stop as quickly as possible, however, it is the up to the thread's implementation (ie, your own code in this case) to handle the interrupt.

Setting the `killMeBoolean` will only have an effect when the thread runs and checks the corresponding variable. To do that, you can use either method from above.

Comment: It depends on your implementation if 1 or 4 is correct. If 1 is correct, 2 should work too. 3 and 4 are basically the same, but 3 might cause errors from racing conditions.